MariaDB: Change the collation of a table containing a JSON column
In MariaDB the type JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_bin.
When I change the collation of a table containing a JSON column to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci  via
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

will that change the collation of the JSON column as well?
If so: Does that pose a problem for the usability of said JSON column?

Structural chars are not collation-dependent.

highly recommend always encoding JSON as ascii for storage or transmission (with \u escapes for any other chars) and never having to worry about encoding


will that change the collation of the JSON column as well?

Yes it will.


If so: Does that pose a problem for the usability of said JSON column?

Some problems that I can think off:

The collation change itself does not affect whether the JSON data remains valid, but impacts how string comparisons within JSON queries work. Queries that rely on case-sensitive or binary comparisons might produce different results after the collation change.

Using utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci, comparisons become case-insensitive which might differ from the behavior of utf8mb4_bin  where comparisons are case-sensitive.

Using utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci might impact performance, especially for complex queries with string operations.



My suggestion.
Revert json column back to LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
ALTER TABLE myTable 
  MODIFY COLUMN json_data LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;


See example

Thanks, that was very clear and helpful!
